# c# winforms, упаковка в .EXE с БД

Tags: c#

помогите пожалуйста разобраться, я пытаюсь собирать программу с БД (SQlite ) в .EXE файл, компилируется, после открываю приложение, пытаюсь вводит логин пароль ( они хранятся внутри базы данных) выдает такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: try{ "Весь ваш код" }catch(Exception e) {  MessageBox.Show("{0} Exception caught.", e); }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007967/net-framework-error-hresult-0x8007000b

Comment: добавил скринь  описанием ошибки , может хоть что-то прояснить ситуацию ....

Comment: написано, что у вас исключение в подключении к базе данных. Проверьте строку подключения, точно ли она корректна и даёт подключиться к БД

Comment: при компиляции прекрасно работает,  добавляет и удаляет данные из БД, у меня таблица с базами данных сделано через DB browser SQLite , но когда собираю в .EXE файлы базами данных невидно в проекте